# How to get Access Token in postman response

Tags: postman

I want to get box access token in the postman response(JSON). how do we achieve this?

Below i have tried.

```
http method: POST

URL: https://api.box.com/2.0/oauth2/token

Authorization: Basic Auth (clientid:client secret)

Body: grant_type=client_credentials
```

But, i couldn't able to get the access token in response.

I am receiving the below error.

```
{
    "type": "error",
    "status": 400,
    "code": "bad_request",
    "context_info": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "reason": "invalid_parameter",
                "name": "entity-body",
                "message": "Invalid value 'grant_type=client_credentials'. Entity body should be a correctly nested resource attribute name/value pair"
            }
        ]
    },
    "help_url": "http://developers.box.com/docs/#errors",
    "message": "Bad Request",
    "request_id": "ctssgkghdwpw9dxh"
}
```

any idea why i am getting the above error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Images can't be seen

Comment: Maybe your body must be JSON? `{"grant_type": "client_credentials"}`

Comment: Yes,the same i have passed

Answer (score 0):

Go to their [API documentation](https://developer.box.com/reference/post-oauth2-token/)

There is cURL example. Copy it's content. [In Postman](https://blog.postman.com/curl-and-postman-work-wonderfully-together/) go to top-left corner <kbd>Import</kbd> -> `Raw Text` -> Paste. It will make cURL in Postman.

---

So from that:

1. In `Body` tab select `x-www-url-encoded` from dropdown
2. In `Key` column enter `grant_type`
3. In `Value` column enter `client_credentials`

[image]

Comment: in Authorization i have passed username:client id and password:client secret and in body i have passed as you said grant_type=client_credentials. Still the same issue

Comment: @kamal Can you provide link to documentation that you rely on doing request?

Comment: I have followed this link for the configuration "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/get-an-access-token-postman/#:~:text=Enter%20the%20https%3A%2F%2Fapi,secret%20in%20the%20Password%20box."

Comment: I have a requirement as, i need to get access token in the response of an endpoint URL. So, i just connected with box and trying to get Access token in the response.

Comment: Amm... I don't get it. In question you use `box.com`, but now you show me PayPal API docs? You can't use one docs for another API

Comment: Yes, By refering paypal link, i have configured box.com appplication